# Exclude Significant Term Aggregation With Different Field

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, recommendation-engine, elasticsearch-aggregation, significant-terms

Is it possible to filter the bucket list result of significant term aggregations using multiple fields to be filtered?
I am trying to create a recommendation feature using ES based on this article at medium https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-recommendation-engine-quick-and-simple-aec8c71a823e.

I store the search data as array of objects instead of array of strings, because i need other fields to be filtered to get correct bucket list result. Here is the index mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "user": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      },
      "comic_subscribes": {
        "properties": {
          "genres": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have 2 conditions to be filtered:

1. comic_subscribes.type must be "serial" only
2. comic_subscribes.genre must not in "hentai" or "echii"

I have already tried two methods to apply the conditions. First i tried to filter it using bool query like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "comic_subscribes.id": "1"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "comic_subscribes.type": "serial"
                }
            },
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "comic_subscribes.genres": "hentai"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "comic_subscribes.genres": "echii"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "recommendations": {
            "significant_terms": {
                "field": "comic_subscribes.id",
                "exclude": ["1"],
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And filter aggregation method:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "comic_subscribes.id": "1"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "comic_subscribes.type": "serial"
                        }
                    },
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "comic_subscribes.genres": "hentai"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "comic_subscribes.genres": "echii"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "minimum_should_match": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "recommendations": {
                    "significant_terms": {
                        "field": "comic_subscribes.id",
                        "exclude": ["1"],
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But still, both of methods give me unfiltered comic bucket lists. Is it any other way to achieve these required conditions? Should i create one more field which store pre-filtered comic list to be used as source field significant term? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add sample data with actual and expected result

Comment: Thank you jaspreet, i think i have found the way to solve this problem. CMIIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, bros. I think there is no option method to filter aggregation significant terms bucket list result using different field.

Based on elasticsearch documentation [Significant Terms Aggregation Parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2), which refers to [Terms Aggregation Filtering Value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4). There is no other option than **filter using partition expression** and **filter values with exact values** (which i have been using as above, **"exclude"** param).

So i create other way around by getting the comic ids which i want to exclude and store it as excludeComics variable in array. Then use the excludeComics var in **exclude** param. And boom, there you go. Filtered significant terms aggregation bucket list result.